# How to send and recieve data from one domain to another?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, subdomain, router

I am using angular 6 application with typescript, Here I am having two domains namely

`authen.helloworld.com` for **authentication** and

`app.helloworld.com` for **application**.

If the user is logged in successfully then redirection will happen from `authen.helloworld.com` to `app.helloworld.com`.

Here in authen , I will get token to say `123456` which I am in the need to retrieve in `app` domain.

Code i have used in authentication,

```
onSignIn() {
    this.ngiAuthenService.postRest(signinurl,signindata).subscribe(res => {
    if (res.status === "true") {
       localStorage.setItem("token",123456)
       window.location.href = app.helloworld.com;
    }
});
```

Here if the status is true, the redirection will take place, where I need to send the token (which will be generated once the user is successfully logged in)  to another domain.

How can I get the token value from one domain to another domain while redirecting?

Comment: you can pass it to query string

Answer (score 2):

Angular is made to make HTTP calls to APIs.

If you wish to redirect to other pages, then you should not use a SPA framework.

Taht being said, you have two options that I see :

1 - Make 2 API calls in Angular, and use the reponses to log your user in.

2 - Redirect to an authentication page, that will redirect to your application with a token in the URL.

Both methods have their advantages and drawbacks, so I can't advise you which one to choose.

Comment: You mean to use, ```this.router.navigateByUrl('/app');```

Comment: No, I mean literally redirecting to `authen`, then `app`. No relation to Angular's router.

Comment: Is it possible to pass that token in hidden mode. I should not show that token in the url but need to get in ```app```. In angular we can achieve by using skiplocation: true.. But here how can i use it?

Comment: You have to understand that Angular's router and your browser behavior are two different things. And I'm not sure it is possible, because I've never seen it in action, so I would tell you no from personal experience.